# How do I download videos from Pexels API?

Tags: python

I have this code that can pull images off of Pexels, but I don't know how to change it to video. I haven't seen anyone do this before and any help greatly appreciated. I tried switching all the photo tags to videos but that seemed not to work. I've also tried adding more libraries but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
import argparse
import json
import os
import time

import requests
import tqdm
from pexels_api import API

PEXELS_API_KEY = os.environ['PEXELS_KEY']
MAX_IMAGES_PER_QUERY = 100
RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 10
PAGE_LIMIT = MAX_IMAGES_PER_QUERY / RESULTS_PER_PAGE


def get_sleep(t):
    def sleep():
        time.sleep(t)
    return sleep


def main(args):
    sleep = get_sleep(args.sleep)

    api = API(PEXELS_API_KEY)
    query = args.query

    page = 1
    counter = 0

    photos_dict = {}

    # Step 1: Getting urls and meta information
    while page <= PAGE_LIMIT:
        api.search(query, page=page, results_per_page=RESULTS_PER_PAGE)
        photos = api.get_entries()

        for photo in tqdm.tqdm(photos):
            photos_dict[photo.id] = vars(photo)['_Photo__photo']
            counter += 1

        if not api.has_next_page:
            break

        page += 1
        sleep()

    print(f"Finishing at page: {page}")
    print(f"Images were processed: {counter}")

    # Step 2: Downloading
    if photos_dict:
        os.makedirs(args.path, exist_ok=True)

        # Saving dict
        with open(os.path.join(args.path, f'{query}.json'), 'w') as fout:
            json.dump(photos_dict, fout)

        for val in tqdm.tqdm(photos_dict.values()):
            url = val['src'][args.resolution]
            fname = os.path.basename(val['src']['original'])
            image_path = os.path.join(args.path, fname)

            if not os.path.isfile(image_path):  # ignore if already downloaded
                response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

                with open(image_path, 'wb') as outfile:
                    outfile.write(response.content)
            else:
                print(f"File exists: {image_path}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--query', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--path', type=str, default='./results_pexels')
    parser.add_argument('--resolution', choices=['original', 'large2x', 'large',
                                                 'medium', 'small', 'portrait',
                                                 'landscape', 'tiny'], default='original')
    parser.add_argument('--sleep', type=float, default=0.1)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

Comment: did you found the solution ?

Answer (score 4):

sorry for bumping into the question. I just faced a similar situation when downloading the videos from Pexels using the python API, pexelsPy. This may be helpful:

I retrieved the ID of the videos and then created the downloading URL that has the following structure: `"https://www.pexels.com/video/"+ ID +"/download"`.

See the following example:

```
def download_video(type_of_videos):

    video_tag = random.choice(type_of_videos)
    PEXELS_API = '-' #please add your API Key here
    api = API(PEXELS_API) 

    retrieved_videos = read_already_download_files('downloaded_files.txt')
    video_found_flag = True
    num_page = 1

    while video_found_flag:

        api.search_videos(video_tag, page=num_page, results_per_page=10)
        videos = api.get_videos()

        for data in videos:
            if data.width > data.height: #look for horizontal orientation videos
                if data.url not in retrieved_videos:
                    # write_file('downloaded_files.txt', data.url)
                    url_video = 'https://www.pexels.com/video/' + str(data.id) + '/download' #create the url with the video id
                    r = requests.get(url_video)
                    with open(data.url.split('/')[-2]+'.mp4', 'wb') as outfile:
                        outfile.write(r.content)
                    return data.url.split('/')[-2]+'.mp4' #download the video

        num_page += 1
```

`download_video` function takes an array of strings with several tags, e.g.: ['happy','sad','relax']. Then it randomly chooses one of these tags.

PEXELS_API should contain your API Key.

`read_already_download_files('downloaded_files.txt')`: Retrieves already downloaded files to check if the current found file is already downloaded.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you be a little more specific, regarding how your post answers the question?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the welcoming. Yes, sure. Q: How do I download videos from Pexels API? A: I retrieved the ID of the videos and then created the downloading URL that has the following structure: "https://www.pexels.com/video/"+ ID +"/download". Then I just request the created URL and save the file, i.e., the downloaded video. Regards.

Comment: @inou It would be helpful to other users if you were able to describe the workings of your function and its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pypexels import PyPexels
import requests
api_key = 'api id'
# instantiate PyPexels object
py_pexel = PyPexels(api_key=api_key)
search_videos_page = py_pexel.videos_search(query="love", per_page=40)
# while True:
for video in search_videos_page.entries:
    print(video.id, video.user.get('name'), video.url)
    data_url = 'https://www.pexels.com/video/' + str(video.id) + '/download'
    r = requests.get(data_url)
    print(r.headers.get('content-type'))
    with open('sample.mp4', 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(r.content)
        # if not search_videos_page.has_next:
    break
        # search_videos_page = search_videos_page.get_next_page()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to do the same. When I was looking for it, I wanted a simple example. All other fancy stuff I was sure I could add myself. So, I built upon [inou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15703457/inou)'s answer. The shown example is very basic and requests one page with only 5 results using the 'Tiger' tag in the search query. I download the first video using its id provided by the response and simply write it to the source folder. The api is provided by *pexelsPy* and the request is executed using the standard *requests* package. To get access to the API, you need to create a key on pexels website (see [here](https://www.pexels.com/api/)). Once you get your own API key, you should be able to simply substitute the shown example key and run the code as a test.

```
import pexelsPy
import requests

PEXELS_API = '16gv62567257256iu78krtuzwqsddudrtjberzabzwzjsrtgswnr'
api = pexelsPy.API(PEXELS_API)

api.search_videos('Tiger', page=1, results_per_page=5)
videos = api.get_videos()
url_video = 'https://www.pexels.com/video/' + str(videos[0].id) + '/download'
r = requests.get(url_video)
with open('test.mp4', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly, I modified it so that we can download multiple videos,you can see my answer below